# Retrieve data from firebase by using query

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i want to get data from firebase by using query. i am able to retrieve and it's show in console of android, but it's doesn't show me in android app. In android it's show me the last use data.

```
usuarios.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            DatabaseReference eventos = ds.getRef().child("eventos");
            System.out.println("eventos:"+eventos);

            for (int i = 0; i < categorias.size();i++){
                String categoria = categorias.get(i).toString();

                if (value.equals(categoria)){
                    eventoFirebaseListOptions = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Evento>()
                            .setQuery(eventos,Evento.class)
                            .setLayout(R.layout.layout_evento)
                            .setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner())
                            .build();
                }else if (value!=categoria){
                    eventoFirebaseListOptions = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Evento>()
                            .setQuery(eventos.orderByChild("categoria").equalTo(value),Evento.class)
                            .setLayout(R.layout.layout_evento)
                            .setLifecycleOwner(getViewLifecycleOwner())
                            .build();
                }
            }

            final FirebaseListAdapter<Evento> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Evento>(eventoFirebaseListOptions) {
                @Override
                protected void populateView(View v, Evento evento, int position) {

                    //Muestra el value de cada campo de la base de datos
                    TextView txtTitol = v.findViewById(R.id.txtTitol);
                    TextView txtDescripcio = v.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
                    ImageView imageView = v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);


                    txtTitol.setText(evento.getTitol());
                    txtDescripcio.setText(evento.getDescripcion());
                    Glide.with(getContext()).load(evento.getImagenUrl()).into(imageView);

                }
            };

            ListView lvEventos = view.findViewById(R.id.lvEventos);
            lvEventos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I want get data that has "SMIX" categoria, the category is dynmic it could be another also.

Here is my JSON DATA

```
  "usuarios" : {
    "UvTCjIYMA0btE14QHz7twbdN7zT2" : {
      "eventos" : {
        "-LdPfYoRre18oGpd3Oda" : {
          "caducidad" : "2019-04-26",
          "categoria" : "SMIX",
          "descripcion" : "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the",
          "horaDelEvento" : "12:12",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/usuarios%2FUvTCjIYMA0btE14QHz7twbdN7zT2%2Fimagenes%2Fpexels-photo-160107.jpeg?alt=media&token=f0b7b573-8ca4-4fd2-a5e4-da43b967ff4b",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "Aula 33",
          "titol" : "Lorem Ipsum"
        },
        "-LfKmyXSFiR6MwKQZeJQ" : {
          "caducidad" : "2019-06-08",
          "categoria" : "DAM",
          "descripcion" : "muy fácil",
          "horaDelEvento" : "16:00",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/usuarios%2FUvTCjIYMA0btE14QHz7twbdN7zT2%2Fimagenes%2FCaptura%20de%20pantalla%202019-05-17%20a%20las%2016.48.58.png?alt=media&token=f8da7ac8-2a64-45ee-8b4f-79f66f431e54",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "instituto",
          "titol" : "examen"
        }
      }
    },
    "hzqvjnkTdJcyTOPUcEMrAmvEXUo1" : {
      "eventos" : {
        "-LfWFcaFgk4Apwr0zqqZ" : {
          "caducidad" : "1212-12-12",
          "categoria" : "DAM",
          "descripcion" : "Fifa",
          "horaDelEvento" : "12:12",
          "imagenUrl" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/english-app-b2170.appspot.com/o/usuarios%2FhzqvjnkTdJcyTOPUcEMrAmvEXUo1%2Fimagenes%2FCaptura%20de%20pantalla%202019-05-22%20a%20las%2018.07.06.png?alt=media&token=ba173429-affb-4578-85bb-ca73e17d8cdf",
          "sitioDelEvento" : "Aula 33",
          "titol" : "Fifa"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i added the data IN JSON format. Please if you have any question, ask me. this is my final project. I have to submit it.

Comment: What does `usuarios` point to? Please make sure your code is both minimal, and can be run standalone.

Comment: I am creating an app where each user create events under he's user id, because later i user user id for show the user the he created y give him option to edit or delete.

Comment: Please indicate the exact data that you want to get and please also responde with @

Comment: finally i could solve my problem after many hours. I had to create custom adapter. With FirebaseListAdapter it's not possible. Thank to all for helping me